# Standard alternative to 'addmargin' environment

Tags: environments, margins, koma-script

I have an old `.tex` file in **Koma-Script** in which I use the practical environment `addmargin`. Now I have copied part of my old LaTeX code in a new file that is not *Komma-Script*. Therefore the `addmargin` environment produces error.

Is there any package where I can add `addmargin` without the whole koma-script clutter or some easy commands to replace the environment `addmargin`?
What would be the most practical way of replacing something like:

```
\begin{addmargin}[\lengthA]{\lengthB}
   Bla, Bla, Text, Ipsum
\end{addmargin}
```

Comment: You can create our own addmargin easily enough.  IIRC, all it does is put space into \leftskip and \righjtskip.

Comment: @JohnKormylo It would be great, if you write your suggestion as an answer to this question. It can not only be helpful as an answer, but also help LaTeX users understand how margins work and how to manipulate them. (I would absolutely +1 it ;))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could load package `scrextend`:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{addmargin}[2cm]{1cm}
   \lipsum[2]
\end{addmargin}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked seamlessly! I am not a fan of loading packages, if I can define easily a command ( I always think, the more packages I load, the higher the chances my document crashes ). But in this case, I could not imagine a quick `\newenvironment` solution. Loading `scrextend` was the quickest thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple `addmargin`.  It will not work with lists, which recompute `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` internally.  Note also that `addmargin*` is much more complicated.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{addmargin}[2][\empty]{\par
  \rightskip=#2\relax
  \ifx\empty#1\relax \leftskip=\rightskip
  \else \leftskip=#1\relax
  \fi}{\par}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{addmargin}[2cm]{1cm}
   \lipsum[2]
\end{addmargin}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```